# The article before "adjective + person's name"

Tags: word-choice, articles

I am trying to write this sentence, but cannot decide if I should use *a* or *the* here:

> It would be minutes before [**a**/**the**] slightly agitated Mrs.
>   Smith finally finds him in the crowd.

If *the* should be used here, is there any scenario where *a* can be added before a specific person's name? I remember seeing such usage before, but my memory could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically it seems as if it should be *the*.

But there is a well known literary device, perfectly idiomatic, which places the indefinite article in that position. One would use it where one was introducing for the first time, to the reader/listener that Mrs Smith was slightly agitated.

**So if the reader is already aware that Mrs Smith is slightly agitated I would use *the*, if they do not I would use *a***.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of article seems to me to reflect a different emphasis. "*a* slightly agitated Mrs. Smith" means, "Mrs. Smith, a slightly agitated person," while "*the* agitated Mrs. Smith" means the agitated version of Mrs. Smith in contrast to her normally cool and collected self.

Comment: Do you mean that "Mrs. Smith, a slightly agitated person," means that she is always a slightly agitated person?

Comment: "A slightly agitated Mrs Smith" does not imply she is always slightly agitated at all. Envisage a sentence "Having just had her handbag snatched, it was a slightly agitated Mrs Smith who approached the police officer". There is a very good reason why she is unusually agitated, but the indefinite article is perfectly idiomatic. However "Mrs Smith, a slightly agitated person..." suggests to me that that is her normal state.